# Converting overdueDate from a DateTime to string in the format dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00

Tags: c#, date, datetime

How would I convert the value **overdueDate** to from a **DateTime** variable to a string in the format **dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00**?

```
    DateTime overdueDate;
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now; 

    if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-12);
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-13);
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-7);
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-8);
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Friday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-9);
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-10);
    }
    else if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
    {
        overdueDate = today.AddDays(-11);
    }
```

Comment: You don't need that many `if` statements, you can get a numeric value of `DayOfWeek` by casting to an int and then doing some basic arithmetic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only need `Date` part with time set to `00:00:00` you can use the [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and format it like:

```
string str = overdueDate.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss");
```

See: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You haven't initialized your `overdueDate` at the time of declaration, Although you are assigning it some value inside your conditions but compiler can't determine whether any value will be assigned to it. Hence you get the error "Use of unassigned local variable". Just declare it like:

```
DateTime overdueDate = default(DateTime);
```

Comment: You haven't initialized the `overdueDate` , do `DateTime overdueDate = default(DateTime);` at the time of initialization.

Comment: This is my code so far - http://pastebin.com/hizRtpEV. I've done what you've suggested but I'm still getting the error message

Comment: @methuselah, you haven't defined `overdueDate` as I said in my comment and answer. Just replace your declaration of `overdueDate` with `DateTime overdueDate = default(DateTime);` at line 7

Comment: I get the following error message now: `The name 'odDate' does not exist in the current context` and `Use of unassigned local variable 'odDate'`

Comment: @methuselah, declare  `string odDate = string.Empty;` or `string odDate = null;`

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateString = overdueDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

And to give you more detailed information, reference the documentation that exists for [custom date time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

One thing to note here is that `ToString` can string out any date you can conceive based on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, but I believe the following is a more efficient method.

```
DateTime overdueDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
while (overdueDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
    overdueDate = overdueDate.AddDays(-1);
```